# SAP Sybase database replication across VPN

Tags: database, synchronization, sybase

We have a master SAP Sybase database A in country C1 and we need a read only copy of the sybase database B in country C2 (currently hosted in hyper-v). We are currently doing this backup using full and incremental backup.

The problem is that it is taking too long to mail the tape and do full database restore at the site B.

We have established a VPN connection and the bandwidth is not big. We can accept a few day latency.  What are my options besides (using replication server) to do this database synchronisation as corporate situation do not allow spending of extra $.

Our full corporate backup data amounts to 5 TB in size.
Thanks.
Patrick

Comment: This should probably be moved to dba.stackexchange.com, as it's a dba question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Replication Server, the simplest solution is probably to use log shipping.  This utilizes the transaction log from one database to synchronize another database.

After an initial dump of the Database A has been loaded in Database B, you would setup scheduled transaction log dumps, and load those dumps in Database B.  After the initial load, the dump sizes would depend on the database transaction rate, so the more activity in the database, the larger the dumps will be.

A couple of things to note:

- This will likely require more transaction log storage space on Database A.
- Database B will not be accessible during the transaction loading time.

A good description of this and other options can be found in this [SAP article on Business Continuity](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/12/20/business-continuity-with-sap-sybase-ase-server-recovery-solutions/)